# Invalid Regular Expression: missing / Error in Chrome

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm using jQuery to search for a specific string using a regex and then replace that string with some html code. See below

```
var mobile = /0330 3030 036/g;
var landline = /0800 953 0304/g;

var newLandLine = $("body").html().replace(mobile, '<span class="calltracks_lcplccouk-current-mobile-landing-page03">CORRECT</span>');

newLandLine = newLandLine.replace(landline, '<span class="calltracks_lcplccouk-lcplccoukcurrentmobilelandingpage08">CORRECT 2</span>');

$("body").html(newLandLine);
```

This works fine on the surface but when I view the Chrome console I am presented with the error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to reslove this so that the code still functions but the error is no longer displayed?

The HTML I'm using is very basic:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script src="./test2_files/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>This is a test</h1>
    <p>0330 3030 036</p>
    <p>0800 953 0304</p>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (document.cookie.indexOf("l&c-original") >= 0) {} else {
            var mobile = /0330 3030 036/g;
            var landline = /0800 953 0304/g;
            var newLandLine = $("body").html().replace(mobile, '<span class="calltracks_lcplccouk-current-mobile-landing-page03">CORRECT</span>');
            newLandLine = newLandLine.replace(landline, '<span class="calltracks_lcplccouk-lcplccoukcurrentmobilelandingpage08">CORRECT 2</span>');
            $("body").html(newLandLine);
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried to create the regular expressions from the Regex object instead?

Comment: I tried it in console, didn't get any error. Using latest version of Chrome

Comment: I tried the entire code and it's working. Are you sure the syntax error is caused by this piece of code. Check the whole stack trace. Maybe your jquery script is corrupted? Is this the exact code you're using?

Comment: I think you've used `/` for commenting instead of `//`

Comment: P.S. Since you're matching a simple string you don't need to use regex. you can just do `.replace("phone", "replacement")`

Comment: It seems like the error is somewhere else.. it's there a line mentioned
Your code works.
See http://jsfiddle.net/s0vkoao0/

Comment: Thanks you for the feedback. Yes, the code functions correctly, but I am still seeing the error in the console. Unfortunately I need to use a regex as the page I will be adding the code to is slightly more complicated. I have simplified the html code for the sake of this explanation.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. Couldn't find a specific solution but ended up moving the script up to the head tag and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is your HTML that contains 2 occurrences of the strings you are replacing.

You are also replacing `0330 3030 036` in `var mobile = /0330 3030 036/g;` with `<span class="calltracks_lcplccouk-current-mobile-landing-page03">CORRECT</span>`.

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/vI7wX0/1)

Try using:

```
var mobile = /0330 3030 036(?!\/g;)/g;
var landline = /0800 953 0304(?!\/g;)/g;
```